# Reflection - How to get attribute of property?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can i get some parameters (or attributes, if they are called so), with reflection?

```
MyObject x = new MyObject(...);
..........
var propInfo = x.GetType().GetProperty("something");
if (propInfo != null) {
    xyz= propInfo.GetValue(x,null).Metrics.Width //<------ gives error
}
```

Comment: `GetValue` returns `object`. you need to cast it before calling other members. otherwise you would be left with using `dynamic` object

Answer (score 0):

`GetValue` returns `object`.

You need to cast it before calling other members.

```
MyObject x = new MyObject(...);
//..........
var propInfo = x.GetType().GetProperty("something");
if (propInfo != null) {
    MyPropertyType xyz = (MyPropertyType)propInfo.GetValue(x,null);
    if(xyz != null) {
        double width = xyz.Metrics.Width;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you would be left with using `dynamic` object.

```
MyObject x = new MyObject(...);
//..........
var propInfo = x.GetType().GetProperty("something");
if (propInfo != null) {
    dynamic xyz = propInfo.GetValue(x,null);
    if(xyz != null) {
        double width = xyz.Metrics.Width;
    }
}
```